# Bootstrap, col не работает

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

при размере экрана больше 600, две col-ы должны стать рядом а не столбом, пробовал так col-md-6 но не вышло.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.navbar-toggler{
    margin-right: 5%!important;
}
.navbar-brand{
    margin-left: 5%!important;
}
.col{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left:4%;
}
.s{
    margin-right: 7%;
    margin-left: 4%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="en">    
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>    
<body>    
    <div class="pos-f-t">
        <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
            <div class="bg-dark p-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-12 col-md-6 s">
                        <h4 class="text-white">Collapsed content</h4>
                        <p class = "text-muted">Add some information about the album below, the author, or any other background context. Make it a few sentences long so folks can pick up some informative tidbits. Then, link them off to some social networking sites or contact information.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-12 col-md-0">
                        <h4 class="text-white">Contact</h4>
                        <a href="" class="text-white">Follow on Twitter</a>
                        <a href="" class="text-white">Like on Facebook</a>
                        <a href="" class="text-white">Email me</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
                Bootstrap
            </a>
            <div class="btn-nav">
            </div><button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </nav>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

родителю row выруби flex-wrap . И самим колонкам  flex свойства

Comment: Если правильно тебя понял.
.col-12 {
    /* -webkit-box-flex: 0; */
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    /* flex: 0 0 100%; */
    max-width: 100%;
}

Comment: не вышло, так как вы сказали

Comment: странно, попробуй через инкогнито ,может кэш. Такое бывает

Comment: Или просто очисти кэш